# Word to describe a person who enjoys how great others live their lives but not for once considers to have such lives by themselves?

Tags: single-word-requests

I vaguely remember the word that I was encountered earlier that can be roughly summed up as the Title. Not entirely sure if it's a word or a phrase. It's been bugging me for a really long time, i need help!

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean someone who ***lives vicariously***?

> ***[vicarious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vicarious)***- Experienced in the imagination through the feelings or actions of another person. Acting or done for another

Comment: Good word; I think I was looking for a noun that represents such type of person. Like the word "narcissist" concludes the kind of people who just love themselves too much.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but useful nonetheless:

> [Compersion](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compersion) -- 1. The feeling of joy one has experiencing
>   another's joy, such as in witnessing a toddler's joy and feeling joy
>   in response.  2. The feeling of joy associated with seeing a loved one
>   love another; contrasted with jealousy.

It's often described as the opposite of jealousy and is common among parents and the polyamorous.

Comment: It will be nice once that works its way into the dictionaries. Good find.

Comment: It will, eventually, as polyamory becomes more common.  (and as parents realize it fits the happiness that comes from their kids being happy.)

Comment: Thanks for the help though, it is a very useful word. I was looking for something more like "narcissist".